# Biblatex: Redefine cite command to print another field

Tags: bibliographies

In my bibliography I have a custom field. I would like to redefine the `\parencite{}` command so that this field is also printed in the text (not in the bibliography though). In the following example I would like the result not to be

> (Gossens, 1993)

but

> (Gossens, 1993, Example)

I am aware that I could use some sort of post-cite command like `\parencite[][Example]{}` command; however I need to directly refer to the field in my bibliography with a new command, for instance: `\parenciteNEW`. It should be possible with `\DeclareCiteCommand`, but I have had no success to get it done by changing it's settings.

Do you have any ideas about how to achieve this?

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,
        bibencoding=utf8,
        sortcites=true,
        bibwarn=true,
        firstinits=true,
        isbn=false,
        dashed=false,
        maxbibnames=99,
        babel=other,
        backend=biber,
        hyperref=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{myworks.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts",
    custom    = "Example"
}

\end{filecontents}


\addbibresource{myworks.bib} 

\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\begin{document}

Here is an example\parencite{goossens93}.

\selectlanguage{american}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should map the custom field to a known field, e.g. usera. Then you can print it either with `\printfield` in the postnote argument, or use it it some cite command definition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,
        bibencoding=utf8,
        sortcites=true,
        bibwarn=true,
        firstinits=true,
        isbn=false,
        dashed=false,
        maxbibnames=99,
        babel=other,
        backend=biber,
        hyperref=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{myworks.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts",
    custom    = "Example"
}

\end{filecontents}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=custom, fieldtarget=usera]
    }
  }
}

\addbibresource{myworks.bib}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

 \DeclareCiteCommand{\parenciteNEW}[\mkbibparens]
 {\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\ifnum\value{liststop}>2 \finalandcomma\fi\addspace\&\space}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \setunit{\postnotedelim}%
   \printfield{usera}}
  {}
  {%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}

\begin{document}

Here is an example \parencite[\printfield{usera}]{goossens93}.
And another
\parenciteNEW[postnote]{goossens93}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your solution. Mapping it to a known field is a great idea.

Comment: However, adapting it to multiple references (e.g., \parenciteNEW{goossens93,goossens97} won't work the same way because this is an edited postnote field, will it?

Comment: Did you try what happens with multiple references?

Comment: Yes, it does not print the ";" between the two entries.

Comment: Okay, got it, if you enter \multicitedelim between the last empty brackets, it will be fine. :)

Comment: I copied the parencite definition from the apa.cbx, it didn't use \multicitedelim.

Comment: `biblatex-apa`'s `\parencite` does not have the `\multicitedelim` in the *sepcode* in `\DeclareCiteCommand`, but the bibmacro `cite` as defined in `apa.cbx` issues `\setunit{\multicitedelim}` at the end. Because of the `\setunit{\postnotedelim}` `\parenciteNEW` will now have either no `\multicitedelim` or `\postnotedelim` instead of `\multicitedelim`. This can probably be fixed by putting a `\setunit{\multicitedelim}` after `\printfield{usera}`.