# Redefine \parencites

Tags: biblatex

Following up this post ([Biblatex: Redefine cite command to print another field](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276186/biblatex-redefine-cite-command-to-print-another-field/276206#276206)) I would also like to redefine the `\parencites` command, however, nowhere in the original biblatex-apa files I can find the definition of this command. Does anyone know where it is defined?

Comment: AFAIK `\parencites` is just created from `\parencite` via `\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\parencites}[\mkbibparens]{\parencite}{\multicitedelim}` in `biblatex.def`. What exactly do you want to achieve? Do you just want `\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\parenciteNEWs}[\mkbibparens]{\parenciteNEW}{\multicitedelim}`?

Comment: Yes, indeed. This is the solution. Please add it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multi-cite commands such as `\parencites` are just derived from the "normal" cite commands via `\DeclareMultiCiteCommand` in `bibaltex.def`, e.g.

```
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\parencites}[\mkbibparens]{\parencite}{\multicitedelim‌​}
```

To make `\parenciteNEW` from [Biblatex: Redefine cite command to print another field](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/276186/35864) into a multicite version we simply need

```
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\parenciteNEWs}[\mkbibparens]{\parenciteNEW}{\multicit‌​edelim}
```