# redefine \cite command to change its design

Tags: biblatex

I am happy with the alpha style for bibliography; but however I want a special design to be rendered for the `\cite{}` commands, exactly as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276186/biblatex-redefine-cite-command-to-print-another-field).

Here is a minimum working example:

Content of bibli.bib:

```
@book{LAUE09,
    Author = {Kurt Laue and Helmut Stenger},
    Date-Added = {2014-05-06 20:55:13 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2014-05-06 20:55:42 +0000},
    Title = {Strangpressen: Verfahren, Maschinen, Werkzeuge},
    Year = {2009}}
```

Here is the content of test.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

%\usepackage[maxalphanames=1, minalphanames=1, style=alphabetic, backend=biber]{biblatex}

%\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
%  \labelelement{
%    \field[strwidth=100,strside=left]{labelname}
%  }
%  \labelelement{
%    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}    
%  }
%}

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
Here is my link to biblio: \cite{LAUE09}.

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{bibli}

\end{document}
```

However, when I toggle the commented lines, the bibliography does not get printed. I get the \cite rendered as I want, but the bibliography stop being displayed and I got following error at compilation time:

```
Package biblatex Error: File 'global.bbl' not created by biblatex.
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'LAUE09' on page 1 undefined on input line 24.
Package biblatex Error: '\bibliographystyle' invalid.
LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
l.28 \bibliography
              {bibli}
```

Apparently, `bibliography` and `bibliography` commands can't be used with the `\usepackage{biblatex}` package. Some docs indicate using the command `printbibliography` instead. This compiles then without any errors, but no bibliography is getting printed! I like the possibility of `printbibliography` to sort bibliography elements according to their type, and would like if possible to use it.

How can I show my bibliography, while still keeping this particular design for the \cite command?

Comment: When using `biblatex`, remove both `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography`, add `\printbibliography` instead (*all* docs should indicate this), and run `biber` instead of `bibtex`.

Comment: And indicate a pointer to the database using `\addbibresource{<bibname>.bib}`.  Clear all helper files afterwards, they will be regenerated.

Comment: ok, your both comments solved the missing bibliography issue. But now, instead of getting ``[LAUE09]``, I got ``[Laue+09]``!

Comment: Well, I can still use a bash script to sed and capslock Laue+09 to LAUE09 in test.bbl between ``biber`` and ``latex`` commands :s

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit thick, but the output "[LAUE09]" is not really what the link you posted has as its desired format? You can achieve what they do much easier if you use an `authoryear`-type style. If you want capslock of what you have in your MWE use `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[uppercase=true]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}    
  }
}`

Comment: Everything is so awesome now, I got everything working as I wanted to work, thanks to you three guys so much!

Comment: Maybe you can write up an answer yourself then. So we can mark this as solved. Or ask one of those who helped you to write one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I have found, plus some little improvements:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\usepackage[maxalphanames=1,
  minalphanames=1,
  style=alphabetic,
  backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{MyDarkBlue}{rgb}{0,0.08,0.7} 
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=MyDarkBlue,citecolor=MyDarkBlue}

\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[uppercase=true,strwidth=100,strside=left]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}    
  }
}

\addbibresource{bibli.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

Here is my link to biblio : \cite{LAUE09}. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I then just use `pdflatex test.tex`, then `biber test.bcf` which generates `global.bbl` file used by `pdflatex test.tex` again to provide the final document.

The `\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}` let me get ride of the `+` between name and 2-digit-year.